# file.py runs but file.exe doesen't

Tags: python, scikit-learn, exe

I created a script that needs to be called by another program and to do it I converted it to a `.exe` file, however, even if the `file.py` runs perfectly, the `.exe` file keeps crashing with this message:

```
"OSError: [WinError 126] cannot find specified module."
```

Here's the code:

```
from pickle import load
from numpy import array
from sklearn import svm

X = array([[5,0,0.01525,0.02556]])

pickle_in = open('test_model','rb') #recupero il classificatore
clf = load(pickle_in)

print(clf.predict(X))
```

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 174, in __init__
File "ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
OSError: [WinError 126] Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test1.py", line 3, in <module>
    import sklearn as sk
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "c:\users\edoardo\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 80, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "c:\users\edoardo\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "site-packages\sklearn\_distributor_init.py", line 18, in <module>
File "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 176, in __init__
__main__.PyInstallerImportError: Failed to load dynlib/dll 'C:\\Users\\Edoardo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI162242\\sklearn\\.libs\\vcomp140.dll'. Most probably this dynlib/dll was not found when the application was frozen.
[6792] Failed to execute script test1
```

Comment: How did you convert the python file to .exe? And can you please post the full traceback?

Comment: i converted the file using auto-py-to-exe.

Comment: Did your ```.exe``` file is on the same folder where it is created or you move it.If you move it then past it there where it is earlier

Comment: no, the .exe file is in the same folder where it was created.

Comment: try using `pyinstaller`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pyinstaller` to convert a python script, i.e. a `.py` file like `file.py`, to an executable file, i.e. a `.exe` file for Windows like `file.exe`.

Open a Windows Command Prompt and do:

1. `pip install pyinstaller` to install the package `pyinstaller`
2. `cd C:\Users\Yourname\PathToFile\file.py`
3. `pyinstaller --onefile file.py`
4. Now there will be a new folder called `C:\Users\Yourname\PathToFile\dist`, and within this folder there will be an executable, which is what you want.

You can follow the guide [here](https://datatofish.com/executable-pyinstaller/).

Comment: I agree, but change `.py` file to `main.py` before converting to avoid issues

Comment: @pica Sorry I did realise that you were using already using `pyinstaller` until you updated your question with the error message. It now seems to be a problem on the system level (path, library, etc.), but I don't have a Windows machine with me. I suggest that you change the title of your question, and the keywords are better to be "`pyinstaller`" and "[WinError 126] cannot find specified module." for both googling and stack-overflowing.

Comment: at the end the problem was the sklearn library: for some reason it doesn't work in .exe files and now i'm trying to find another way to run my script.